# How to handle distributing lots of large messages to an Akka cluster on startup?

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka-cluster

We have an actor structure where there is a cluster-sharded actor that calculates a parametric matrix of about 7 meg and has to distribute it to five other nodes for consumption. First of all, there are the following constraints:

1. The matrix has to be generated in one place.
2. The matrix is needed on all nodes to handle user load.
3. The matrix will be periodically generated again to handle changing variables and then sent off to all nodes to handle user load.
4. Saving the matrix in a database is probably not viable as it merely shifts the networking load and the database would get very large very fast. The database only saves the input parameters.

We changed the Akka max message size to 10 meg to accomplish this, but that feels a bit odd and we didn't see another choice. Normally this works fine even though passing 10 meg messages around a distributed pub-sub seems odd to me. However, on startup, the system has to start up 2000 of these all at once. As a result the sharding coordinators scream at us about buffered messages. It eventually calms down and life resumes, but I would love to be able to do this without the bloodbath in the logs.

Can someone recommend an alternative strategy for handling the distribution of the parametric matrix that gets it to every node but doesn't cause a shard coordinator complaint bloodbath?